# Golang Gin Gonic c.HTML Access passed interface variables inside nested header/footer template

Tags: go, go-gin

I have template header.html and home.html

```
data:= gin.H{
        "title": "Home",
        "firstname": "firstname",
        "lastname": "lastname",
    }
c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "home.html", data)
```

This is my home.html template

```
{{ template "header.html" }}
<!-- BEGIN: Content-->
<div class="app-content content ">
    <div class="content-overlay"></div>
    <div class="header-navbar-shadow"></div>
    <div class="content-wrapper">

  </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- END: Content-->
{{ template "footer.html" }}
```

**I am able to access all three variables(title, firstname, lastname) inside home.html with {{ .firstname }} but unable to access inside header.html or footer.html**

This is how I am loading my static and templates

```
router.Static("/static", "./static")
router.LoadHTMLGlob("templates/**/*.html")
```

Please note my template is working fine as my header + home + footer content is loading and working properly except variables.

Comment: you should be able to pass variables to nested templates, like `{{ template "header.html" . }}` (see the dot after template name)

Comment: Thanks very much friend. Its working now.